# Generic RawRepresentable Protocol property

Tags: ios, swift, struct, enums, protocols

I am looking to write a `protocol` which will be used with a variety of measurement structs. Each of these structs has its own Units enumeration which is used to define the unit types for comparison:

```
public enum TestUnits: Double {
  case foo = 100.0
  case var = 1000.0
}
```

All the enumerations are of type `Double` and conform to `RawRepresentable`. I am looking for a way to create a generic protocol property which each `Struct` can set their own unit enumeration for comparison and formatting:

```
protocol UnitMeasuable {

   var measurementType : SOMETHING<RawRepresentable> { get} 

   func someFormattingFunc(type: measurementType) -> String
}
```

I am just unclear how I can declare the measurementType so that it will be set by the individual struct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would you have two options.

# Use associatedtype on your protocol

```
 protocol UnitMeasuable {
 associatedtype Something where Something: RawRepresentable

   var measurementType: Something { get} 
   func someFormattingFunc(type: Something) -> String
}
```

or go forget about the variable (I see no reason you should have that property, but I really don't know what's your plan) and use a generic in the function.

```
protocol UnitMeasuable {
   func someFormattingFunc<Type: RawRepresentable>(type: Type) -> String
}
```

Hope this helps!